# Java convert text file to comma seperated file

Tags: java, file

I have a text file which looks like this:

```
ExampleA1
ExampleA1b

ExampleA2
ExampleA2b

ExampleA3
ExampleA3b
```

Could someone please help me in converting it to a comma separated format like:

```
ExampleA1, ExampleA1b
ExampleA2, ExampleA2b
ExampleA3, ExampleA3b
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: `Could someone please help me`, Ok. What you have tried ?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)  I mean *besides* asking us.

Comment: Take a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileReader.html for a start, try to get the text file read in and print it, then start manipulating it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might use something like this

```
File f = new File("temp/file.txt");
if (!f.exists()) {
  return;
}
Scanner scanner = null;
List<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
try {
  scanner = new Scanner(f);
  while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    String line1 = scanner.nextLine().trim();
    if (line1.length() == 0) {
      continue;
    }
    String line2 = "";
    if (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
      line2 = scanner.nextLine().trim();
    }
    if (line2.trim().length() > 0) {
      al.add(line1 + ", " + line2);
    } else {
      al.add(line1);
    }
  }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
  scanner.close();
}
FileOutputStream fos = null;
try {
  fos = new FileOutputStream(f, false);
  PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fos);
  for (String str : al) {
    pw.println(str);
  }
  pw.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
  if (fos != null) {
    try {
      fos.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
  }
}
```

Starting with

```
cat file.txt
ExampleA1
ExampleA1b

ExampleA2
ExampleA2b

ExampleA3
ExampleA3b
```

I get this with the above

```
ExampleA1, ExampleA1b
ExampleA2, ExampleA2b
ExampleA3, ExampleA3b
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems very easy work at first sight, but not so easy after a closer look :) Here is the answer:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("/home/venkatesh/Desktop/test.txt");
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fin));
        int data = -1;
        int prevChar = -1;
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        do {
            data = reader.read();
            if (data == -1) break;
            if (data == '\n') {
                if (prevChar == '\n') {
                    baos.write('\n');
                    prevChar = 0;
                } else {
                    prevChar = data;
                }
            } else {
                if (prevChar == '\n') {
                    baos.write(',');
                    baos.write(' ');
                }
                baos.write(data);
                prevChar = data;
            }
        } while (true);
        System.out.println(" Written Text : \n" + new String(baos.toByteArray()));
        reader.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Brief Explanation : Here we are performing following operations:

1. Opening a file through FileInputStream and then wrapping it around by a Reader of choice. Open a Outpustream (I have used ByteArrayOutputStream for logging simplicity here).

2. Read char by char using read() API and checking for few application specific conditions - 

a. If currentReadChar is new line char (\n) and previously no new line char found just jump to next char (don't write anything to output stream)

b. If currentReadChar is newline char and previous is also newline char, then write one newline char instead of two and then conintue to next char.

c. If currentReadChar is not a newline char and previous is one newline char, then write ', ' to the stream before writing current char

d. If currentReadChar is not a newline char and previous one is too not a newline char, write the current char.

3. Close the streams/readers and use the resulting outputstream/string whatever you want to.

Basic Assumptions:

1. There is a single new line char between ExampleA1 and ExampleA1b

2. There are two new line chars between next group of ExampleA...

Hope this helps...